# Nodejs for analytics data dumping in flat file

Tags: node.js

We are planning to use nodejs instead of tomcat or jetty. But we ran some test around it and node is performing slower than jetty. Test case we ran is on 8 core machine with 32gb of ram. For test we used 1000000 requests with 1000 concurrency. We used cluster module, url module, http module and os module with stream. Does these module add any overhead…? Is there any optimization that we could do to better the performance. Following is the code for node.

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var cluster = require('cluster');
var fs = require('fs');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var stream = [];
if (cluster.isMaster) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
                cluster.fork();

        }
        cluster.on('death', function(worker) {
                console.log('worker ' + worker.pid + ' died');
        });
}
else{
    var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.end();
    });
    stream = fs.createWriteStream("nodejsCluster"+cluster.worker.id+".txt");
    stream.once('open', function(fd) {
        server.listen(8084);
    });
    server.on('request', function(request, response){
            var parsedUrl = url.parse(request.url, true, true);
            var queryAsObject = parsedUrl.query;
            stream.write( ( new Date()  )+'This is the content to write into file '+queryAsObject.test+"\n");
    });
    console.log("Server is listening"+cluster.worker.id);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: [Be sure you are testing load in a real-world scenarios](https://webtide.com/lies-damned-lies-and-benchmarks-2/).  Jetty is optimized for real world usage and latency.  Not for unrealistic load scenarios.

Comment: We are expecting pick traffic of 2500 req per sec(in spikes).

Comment: Seeing as [Jetty can handle 320,000 to 448,000 req per sec on a single i7 machine right now](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r8&hw=i7&test=plaintext), sounds like your benchmarks are not written to real world scenarios.

Comment: Last link helped us lot in our decision making. Thanks. But can we optimize above mentioned code.